# Not able to cover code for entire class

Tags: apex, unit-test

Please find my class:

```
   Coupon_Request__c Crequest =new Coupon_Request__c(
                                                 Coupon__c = cb.Id,
                                                 Account__c = opp.AccountId, 
                                                 Notes__c = ' ',
                                                 Reason__c = 'TMS Test via Boomi',
                                                 Status__c = 'Approved',
                                                 Approved_Date__c = d,
                                                 Project_Value__c = 100,
                                                 Amount_Picklist__c = '100',
                                                 Expiration_Period__c = '30'
                                                 );
```

Comment: Remove the try-catch in your unit test method. It may be causing the unit test to pass despite a DML error.

Comment: if you are sure that you fully wrote your test class to cover all possible(and impossible) scenarios and you still have uncovered lines: do you even need them?

Comment: Please remove only irrelevant code. This Q&A combo now makes zero sense.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your unit test is silently discarding DML errors. This sort of try-catch block shouldn't generally be in a unit test. It's generally better to let the exception through, which will cause a unit test failure, than to ignore the errors. You want all of your unit tests to pass, but not by cheating.

Change this code:

```
try{
        insert Crequest;
    }catch(DmlException ex){
        System.debug('--exception--'+ex.getMessage());
    }
```

To this code:

```
        insert Crequest;
```

Preferably, if you do want to handle DML errors (e.g. you *expect* a DML operation to fail), you should prefer to use Database.SaveResult, Database.DeleteResult, etc instead of using try-catch, because it may be misleading.